# Android Array in SQL Query

Tags: android, sqlite, autocompletetextview

Sorry, I'm newbie... :)
please take a minute's time to help me and forgive me for my bad english

I have made autocompletetextview with data coming from the database that also I have made with use SQLite, for example as follows

table country
column name | column code
United States | USA
Brazil | BRA
England | ENG
France | FRA
China | CHI
Japan | JPN

well, this time I've done a data call using either country name and country code through autocompletetextview. Success and without error. before accessing previous autocompletetextview must select the option to use the spinner with a choice

1. Europe
2. America
3. Asia

after selecting the option on the spinner, the application will make deliveries http post to the server, **and the server responds only country code**.

the problem that I face, how to display suggestion autocompletetextview by the selected spinner. For example, the user selects Asia then suggestion on autocompletetextview only display china and japan.

I inform some pieces of code :

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence userInput, int start, int before,
        int count) {

    try {
        PopulateAutoComplete[] myObject = databaseHandler.readCodeRoutes("SUB", userInput.toString());
        routesAdapter = new AutocompleteCustomArrayAdapter(context,
                R.layout.list_view_row, myObject);
        etBerangkat.setAdapter(routesAdapter);
        etKembali.setAdapter(routesAdapter);

        routesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I use that way, each typing on autocompletetextview will access the database one by one word. before the user selects option on the spinner :

```
public PopulateAutoComplete[] readCodeRoutes(String country) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    sql += " WHERE " + fieldObjectName + " LIKE '%" + country + "%'";
    sql += " ORDER BY " + fieldObjectId + " DESC";
}
```

after the user selects option on the spinner. I tried this, but it does not bring up suggestions on autocompletetextview

```
public PopulateAutoComplete[] readCodeRoutes(String world, String country) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    sql += " WHERE " + fieldObjectName + " LIKE '%" + country+ "%'";
    sql += " AND " + fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '%" + world + "%'"; <-- I add this
    sql += " ORDER BY " + fieldObjectId + " DESC";
}
```

if I write it on the line a second query in sql

```
sql += " AND " + fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '%" + world + "%'";
```

to be :

```
sql += " AND " + fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '%CHI%'";
```

then suggestion on autocompletetextview only display china.

and my question how easy way to display the suggestion based on the spinner selection. I think by using an array in query sql but as far as I'm trying until now always error. Please help me :((

in case of response from server give name country dan code country then it will not be as complex as this, but the server only provides the country code

Comment: which db you are using ? mysql ?sqlserver ? or sqllite ? i think it is sqllite am i right ?

Comment: yes, sqlitedatabase android

Comment: then remove all other tag from your question

Comment: forgive me, I was too excited

Comment: your like statement part  seems to be incorrect according to your scenario

Comment: can you tell me what will be the value of string country here ? public PopulateAutoComplete[] readCodeRoutes(String country)

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple parameter for your WHERE, in your case you can use OR like :

```
sql += " AND ( " + fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '%CHI%' + " OR " + fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '%JPN%' + " )";
```

If you have an array of parameter, you can use a loop to build your WHERE condition like :

```
ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<String>();
        tab.add("CHI");
        tab.add("FR");
        String where = "";
        for(int i=0; i<tab.size(); i++) {
            where += fieldObjectKode + " LIKE '% "+ tab.get(i) +"%'";
            if(i < tab.size() - 1) {
                where += " OR ";
            }
        }

        if(!"".equals(where)) {
            sql += " AND ( " + where + " )";
        }
```